# JMeter JSON Path Extractor expression issue while searching arrays

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jsonpath

My HTTP request returns an array similar to

```
[
{"id":"1", "data":"abc"},
{"id":"2", "data":"def"},
{"id":"3", "data":"ghi"}
]
```

As an input for a ForEach Controller I'm trying to extract the ids of above result into an array using a JSON Path Extractor with a Path expression of $..id.
I'm expecting to get something similar to ["1", "2","3"] but the output I get is

```
ids=3
ids_matchNr=3
```

It appears that the JSON Path Extractor only matches/extracts the last occurrence of id instead of collecting all occurrences of the id values and adding them to an aray.

The same expression and data return the expected ["1", "2","3"] result array in jsonpath.curiousconcept.com so the expression seems to be correct.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the JSON Path Extractor?

Below are some screen prints for a little test 
[image: Input Array Declaration]

[image: JSON Extractor]

[image: Debug Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue:

1. [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

   [image: JMeter JSON Extractor]
2. [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/)

   [image: JMeter JSON Path Extractor]

So double check you are using the latest version of JMeter and JSON Path Extractor, the latter one can be upgraded using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri-T for the quick response. I Added a some screen prints of the test I created to the original post. The JMeter version I'm using is a fresh install which I downloaded just yesterday. Will check the JSON Path Extractor version in a little bit

Comment: I installed the plugins manager and and upgraded to the latest JSON Path Extractor but still got the same results. Do you mind pasting a screen shot of your Path Extractor setup?

Comment: Set "Match Numbers" to `-1` and you should get the desired result. Just in case check out [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) article

Comment: Oh man, that's it!!! Thanks so much. I read the article over and over and only in the comments does somebody mention the -1. Anyway, all good now.

Comment: OMFG, thank you very much @DmitriT! I was hopeless after hours of searching on the web and docs and blogs about slicing an array with that json extractor and the only thing nobody mention is this -1! You saved me days of headaches